# Why spring cloud gateway routing is slow? Anything wrong with my configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring could gateway to route to servers based on user accessing api. Few should go through `Wrapper` service - which do some additional work before making all to actual(platform) API and other is the `Platform` service - where actual work will be done

My configuration looks following

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, WrapperAPIPredicateFactory pf) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("platform", r -> r.path("/process/**").and().predicate(pf.apply(new Config()))
                    .uri("https://platform.excample.com"))
            .route("wrapper", r -> r.path("/**")
                    .uri("https://wrapper.excample.com"))
            .build();
}
```

With this, I see the calls which are routed to platform url using spring cloud gateway is taking longer than direct call platform api. i.e direct call took 300ms, the same call from spring cloud gateway routing taking 1000ms

Note: in routing predicate no DB or Network calls

**Update**
Using Spring and Spring Cloud Gateway version as per my gradle configuration

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Without more information from you it is impossible to even guess. What versions are you using? Do you have any interesting logs. Have you enabled wiretap settings on gateway to see what is being sent? Are they on the same network?

Comment: @spencergibb updated about version details. As you mentioned I have gone through documentation to figure out enabling wiretap and will check that and revert with any findings. Also Gateway and wrapper service on the same network in different country and platform in the different network on another country